# how to get current text(font) style of edittext and set it to another edittext?

Tags: android, textstyle

**how to get current text(font) style of edittext and set it to another edittext?**

**code i tried**

**lib i used:*  [easyfonts](https://github.com/vsvankhede/easyfonts)

```
t6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //e1.setText("");

t6.setTypeface(EasyFonts.caviarDreams(getApplicationContext()));
                    text6=t6.getText().toString();
                    e1.setText(text6);
                }
            });
```

**settext method setting normal text not styled**

Comment: What is your exact issue? Do you want same font for 2 edittext ?

Comment: @Amsheer   my issue is when i click on textview(t6) ...  it sets the fontstyle to edittext and i want this fontstyle to set in another edittext ....... but it sets normal fontstyle

Comment: @Amsheer   if u know how to get the current font style of edittext plz let me know

Comment: " when i click on textview(t6) ... it sets the fontstyle to edittext"  from where you are getting this font style?

Comment: @Amsheer thanks for your time contribution   but problem solved after below  comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `editText.getTypeface()` to get the font of an edit text. Similarly, use `editText.setTypeface()` to set the font for another editText.

Consider you have two edit text as `e1` and `e2`, where you want to set font of e2 same as e1 just use `e2.setTypeFace(e1.getTypeFace());`.

Go through the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTypeface()) for more details.